# Who's the burnt guy brought in?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In the last scenes of [*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843866/), after bucky pulls Capt Rogers from the water, and sets him aside, he walks away.

several minutes later, we see paramedics, bring in a guy, he is all burnt, the camera seems to focus on his left hand (indicating to bucky maybe? - if so, I thought that his left hand was amputated during his transformation.

else, who's that guy?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Seems this is S.H.I.E.L.D operative Brock Rumlow. According to Frank Grillo who [plays him](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_America%3a_The_Winter_Soldier#Cast):

> "Very early on the [film's directors] Russos said, 'Look, **this is an origin film for this character.** We're gonna discover who this is and this is a big movie with a lot of moving parts, but we're gonna discover you in this film and, you know, here's the information about who Brock Rumlow turns into and blah, blah, blah.' And so we've had multiple discussions about what comes after that, that thing. So, you know, **it's obvious Rumlow is covered in rubble and burned to [a] crisp at the end, but you see he's still there. They don't do that for no reason."**

So this appears to be a set up for Rumlow's alter-ego [Crossbones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbones_%28comics%29), a Red Skull henchman involved in the [assassination of Captain America](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Captain_America). This [site](http://www.fatmovieguy.com/captain-america-the-winter-soldier-easter-eggs-secrets-and-trivia/) is one of several that support the theory (scroll down about 2/3 of the way).